# TFJS predict vs Python predict

Tags: tensorflow, keras, prediction, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow.js

I trained my model using Keras in Python and I converted my model to a tfjs model to use it in my webapp. I also wrote a small prediction script in python to validate my model on unseen data. In python it works perfectly, but when I'm trying to predict in my webapp it goes wrong.

This is the code I use in Python to create tensors and predict based on these created tensors:

```
input_dict = {name: tf.convert_to_tensor([value]) for name, value in sample_v.items()}
predictions = model.predict(input_dict)
classes = predictions.argmax(axis=-1)
```

In TFJS however it seems I can't pass a dict (or object) to the predict function, but if I write code to convert it to a tensor array (like I found on some places online), it still doesn't seem to work.

```
  Object.keys(input).forEach((k) => {
    input[k] = tensor1d([input[k]]);
  });
  console.log(Object.values(input));

  const prediction = await model.executeAsync(Object.values(input));
  console.log(prediction);
```

If I do the above, I get the following error: `The shape of dict['key_1'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [-1,1], but was [1]`

If I then convert it to this code:

```
  const input = { ...track.audioFeatures };
  Object.keys(input).forEach((k) => {
    input[k] = tensor2d([input[k]], [1, 1]);
  });
  console.log(Object.values(input));
```

I get the error that some dtypes have to be int32 but are float32. No problem, I can set the dtype manually:

```
  const input = { ...track.audioFeatures };
  Object.keys(input).forEach((k) => {
    if (k === 'int_key') {
      input[k] = tensor2d([input[k]], [1, 1], 'int32');
    } else {
      input[k] = tensor2d([input[k]], [1, 1]);
    }
  });
  console.log(Object.values(input));
```

I still get the same error, but if I print it, I can see the datatype is set to int32.

I'm really confused as to why this is and why I can't just do like python and just put a dict (or object) in TFJS, and how to fix the issues I'm having.

**Edit 1: Complete Prediction Snippet**

```
  const model = await loadModel();  
  const input = { ...track.audioFeatures };
  Object.keys(input).forEach((k) => {
    if (k === 'time_signature') {
      input[k] = tensor2d([parseInt(input[k], 10)], [1, 1], 'int32');
    } else {
      input[k] = tensor2d([input[k]], [1, 1]);
    }
  });

  console.log(Object.values(input));
  const prediction = model.predict(Object.values(input));
  console.log(prediction);
```

**Edit 2: added full errormessage**
[image: full console.log]

Comment: If you get the errror that the data is not `int32`, it probably is that you did not cast all your data to `int32`. There is even an error in your code. You cannot reassign to a const. It will throw an error

Comment: I'm never assigning to a const, but to the key of the const. If you const an object, you can still assign property/values to it :) I did cast the one with the error, and in the error it says it's still a float32, but if I console.log, I can see it is converted to int32

Comment: Sorry, you are right. You are reassigning the prop/values instead. Can you please show your complete code and the complete error ? By complete code I mean how you are using the input for prediction after casting it.

Comment: Done! Added it to the question. If I log the input[k] inside the if, it prints with dtype int32, so i'm pretty sure it sets it correctly? I even added a parseInt to be sure it's an integer that's passed as input data... The model is a graphmodel.

Comment: Another thing I find odd is that it asks for shape [-1, 1], but I can't set negative shape inside the tensor2d()

Comment: You cannot create a tensor2d with a shape whose some dimensions size are -1. However you can reshape a tensor with some axis set to -1. You did not add the whole error message

Comment: I Added the latest error and the console.log from inside the if now. The shape error I only get if I use tensor1d.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218682/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-jc97).